# Mongoose find with default value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model: (With a field that has a default)

```js
var MySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    isClever: { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false 
    }
});
```

I can save a model of this type by just saving a name and in mongoDB, only name can be seen in the document (and not isClever field). That's fine because defaults happen at the mongoose level. (?)

The problem I am having then is, when trying to retrieve only people called john and isClever = false:

```js
MySchema.find({
    'name' : 'john', 
    'isClever': false
}).exec( function(err, person) {
        // person is always null
});
```

It always returns null. Is this something related to how defaults work with mongoose? We can't match on a defaulted value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html), default values are applied when the document skeleton is constructed.

When you execute a `find` query, it is passed to Mongo when no document is constructed yet. Mongo is not aware about defaults, so since there are no documents where `isClever` is explicitly `true`, that results in empty output.

To get your example working, it should be:

```js
MySchema.find({ 
    'name' : 'john', 
    'isClever': {
        $ne: true
    }
})
```